SQLite in a React Native Expo app results in error
I am trying to add a SQLite database to my React Native Expo app.
To do this, I have created a new Expo app. I have installed the expo-sqlite package using npx expo install expo-sqlite. I have then created the following app in the App.js file:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('myDatabase.db');

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create the database table if it doesn't exist
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, count INTEGER)',
        [],
        (tx, results) => {
          tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT count FROM myTable WHERE id = 1',
            [],
            (tx, results) => {
              if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                setCount(results.rows.item(0).count);
              }
            }
          );
        },
        (tx, error) => {
          console.error('Error creating table:', error);
        }
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const updateCount = () => {
    // updateCount function
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>You clicked me {count} times</Text>
      <Button title="Press me" onPress={updateCount} />
    </View>
  );
}

This results in the error: SQLite.openDatabase is not a function (it is undefined)
I have tried the same code using expo-sqlite/legacy. expo-sqlite/legacy allows me to use the app. However, after switching the app off, the data is reset.
I want to use expo-sqlite and not expo-sqlite/legacy due to the maintenance of expo-sqlite.
By looking at YouTube videos and asking AI, I have found that I don't need to install SQLite on my machine for this to work on my Expo React Native app.
I am running the code on an Android Emulator
1 example of a webpage showing the SQLite.openDatabase method is React Dev Station under the Imports and Connection heading

The article you've linked is from 2020, which is, by most software standards, particularly stale.
A quick review of the relevant docs indicates that this method was available in the previous major release of Expo (SDK v50) but was subsequently removed in favor of openDatabaseAsync and openDatabaseSync to provide asynchronous and synchronous functionality, respectively.
You could either (a) opt to downgrade Expo to SDK v50 (which I don't believe would be advisable for new code), or (b) simply replace your call to the now-nonexistent openDatabase method with openDatabaseSync:
const db = SQLite.openDatabaseSync('myDatabase.db');

